# A generic callable

Tags: java, generics, callable

I am trying to implement a generic callable to delegate the modification of different types of accounts.
The code looks like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
class Task<T extends BaseAccount> extends Callable<T extends BaseAccount> {

  private final T t;

  public Task(T t) {
    this.t = t;
  }

  @Override
  public T call() throws Exception {
    t.increment();
    return t;
  }

}
```

The BaseAccount is just an abstract class as follows:

```
abstract class BaseAccount {
  abstract public void increment();
}
```

But obviously I am not getting there as I see a lot of generics-related compilation errors.
Would appreciate help through this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, in a class, you don't extend an interface, you implement it.  Second, you don't need to repeat that `T` extends `BaseAccount` in the `Callable` part.  Just do this:

```
class task<T extends BaseAccount> implements Callable<T>
```

**EDIT**

The `<T extends BaseAccount>` in the `task` class declaration is where you have declared your generic type parameter `T`, so a bounds restriction is appropriate here.  But `implements Callable<T>` is just a reference to the type parameter `T`, just like everywhere else in the class where you use `T` -- the instance variable declaration, the constructor and the method.

Additionally, it's conventional for java class names to start with a capital letter, e.g. `Task`, but that's not important for resolving the compiler errors.

Comment: The extends was an oversight - apologies.But appreciate the help on the Callable<T> bit.So does it mean that the type restriction needs mentioning only in the implementing class definition?

Comment: That's correct.  You only define `T` (and use a bounds restriction) with your class definition, and you refer to it everywhere else -- including the `implements clause` (or `extends` if it's a superclass) .